# IDE vs. EXE performance in .NET

Tags: vb.net, ide

I've developed a .NET application that, among other things, does the following:

1. Uses WebClient to retrieve data from a remote server.
2. Serves as a socket server to 2 'satellite' applications run on the same machine or on a LAN.

   When I run the app in the VS IDE, it works great. It quickly gets the data from the remote server and communicates perfectly with the 2 satellites.

   However, when I build it and run it as an EXE, the response from the remote server is very slow and its communication with the 2 satellite applications become very poor.

   Is there some important difference between running an app in the IDE and running it as an EXE that could effect it like this?

take care,
lee

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, the best advice I can provide is to do some profiling.  At the simplest level, this could mean just logging the start/stop of each call (in a log file) that seems slow.  It's quite possible that the problem is a different function call than what you believe.

Once you narrow down your problem, you can post the relevant lines of code with more detail so we can help.

Comment: Hello,

  It is not a code problem. If I run the server in the IDE, it works perfectly. The problem comes in when I run the app as an EXE.

  I did add some logging. The problem seems to be that messages don't get delivered to the satellites. They are sent, but never received. And it is random, leading me to believe it has something to do with the sockets when in the IDE and not in the IDE.

take care,
lee